# Sort multi embedded data in mongodb

Tags: aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Below is my dummy data. **I would like to sort my class X data based on changeddate field from Class Z**. I tried using unwind operation but unfortunately unwind can be used only once. 
I have to unwind Class Z too so that i can do my sorting. But couldn't do it by any means.

Any help will be gladly accepted.

Thanks in advance.

```
 Class X{
        Integer _id;
        Arraylist<Y> objY;
        }

Class Y{
    Integer _id;
    Arraylist<Z> objZ;
    }

Class Z{
        Integer _id;
        String value;
        String oldValue;
        Date changeddate;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

got the answer, it might help someone. this is what i did

```
db.collection.aggregate(     { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        objY: 1
    } },
    { $unwind: '$objY' },
    { $unwind: '$objY.objZ' }
);
```

What this code does is that it will unwind class Y and then unwind class Z so now we can perform any operations.

Thanks